# How can I properly escape javascript tags in a rails partial?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

my file is `_file.html.erb` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    console.log("<%= escape_javascript( list ) %>");
  });
</script>
```

This fails. But if I put in a `debugger` before the javascript gets rendered, and run `list`, it returns properly in console. How can I get an active working JSON object from `list` so that I can work with it?

Comment: Take a look at what gets rendered by checking "View source" in the browser

Comment: @Gareth It returns `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub'`

Comment: You need to give more context to this.  How is this template being rendered?  Where is the `list` variable being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var list = <%= list.attributes.to_json %>;
    console.log(list);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Returns : `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for #<List:0x007f981ad8a630>):`

Comment: What is the list object?  An activerecord object?  Are you just trying to convert the attributes to json?

Comment: Yes, its an AR object. Eventually, once I do get the object, I'd like to pass it in my BB view. So I'd like to convert it to a JSON object.

Comment: I just edited to show you how to convert the attributes to json.

Comment: Your answer would work if Rails was retrievable within the `<script>` call. Nothing I've tried so far will show `list`, let alone its attributes..

Comment: It sounds like you may not be passing the `list` variable to the view properly.  Either you need to use an instance variable or use `:locals => {:list => list}` when rendering.

Comment: Nope, no instance variables will pass through.